# GetElementById from imported nodes

Tags: php, html, dom, getelementbyid

How can I retrieve the ids from the imported nodes?
It's possible with the original xml content, but if I import some data I cannot access it by id.

```
$test = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head/>
    <body>
        <div id="test"></div>
    </body>
</html>';


$test2 = '<div id="test2">test</div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom2 = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($test);
$dom2->loadXML($test2);

$element2 = $dom2->documentElement;

$import = $dom->importNode($element2, true);

$element = $dom->getElementsByTagName('html')->item(0);
$element->appendChild($import);

var_dump($dom->getElementById('test'));
var_dump($dom->getElementById('test2'));
```

It is possible to find test but not to find test2 which came by the imported element.

That is the xml output. The import worked.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="test"></div>
    </body>
    <div id="test2">test</div>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the importNode would behave since there's no obvious information as to where you actually want to insert the element2 node. Try adding body tags around the div of $test2, so the importNode will then (maybe) understand you want to import it there.

Comment: I edited my post. The import is working, but if I try to get some data by test2, it returns null.

Comment: Try what I suggested.

Comment: Unfortunately still the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
I had to add this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html_fragment
    <!ATTLIST div id ID #IMPLIED>
]>
```